How to Perform SQL-like Update Operations on a PySpark DataFrame Using SQL Queries?
I am trying to perform in-memory updates on a very large PySpark DataFrame instead of making disk-based updates in a PostgreSQL database. I chose PySpark for its speed and scalability over direct database updates.
Here's what I'm doing:

I have a .csv file named source_table_details that I read and convert into a PySpark DataFrame.
I perform some data manipulations like:
df = df.withColumn('column1', df['column2'] * 2)
df = df.withColumn('column2', concat(['column1', 'column2']))


The final step would be to load this DataFrame into a database table.

However, I want to perform complex update operations similar to what I would do in SQL. For example, I have a SQL query that updates a table based on joins and conditions involving other database tables:
UPDATE source_table_details 
SET remark1 = 'AUTO REVERSAL' 
FROM source_lrsapirefund_tmp_details 
WHERE source_lrscbs_tmp_details.creditdebit = 'CREDIT' 
AND source_lrsapirefund_tmp_details.status NOT IN ('1','2') 
AND source_lrscbs_tmp_details.utrrrnmerge = source_lrsapirefund_tmp_details.refutrno 
AND source_lrsapirefund_tmp_details.refundtype IN ('1','2') 
AND source_lrscbs_tmp_details.remark1 IS NULL;

To execute this query in PySpark, I created a temporary view:
df.createOrReplaceTempView("source_table_details")

I tried to use spark.sql() with this query:
query = """
    UPDATE source_table_details 
    SET remark1 = 'AUTO REVERSAL' 
    FROM source_lrsapirefund_tmp_details 
    WHERE source_lrscbs_tmp_details.creditdebit = 'CREDIT' 
    AND source_lrsapirefund_tmp_details.status NOT IN ('1','2') 
    AND source_lrscbs_tmp_details.utrrrnmerge = source_lrsapirefund_tmp_details.refutrno 
    AND source_lrsapirefund_tmp_details.refundtype IN ('1','2') 
    AND source_lrscbs_tmp_details.remark1 IS NULL;
"""
df_ops.df = spark.sql(query)

But I encountered the error: UPDATE TABLE is not supported temporarily.
Question:
Is there an optimized way to perform SQL-like UPDATE queries directly on a PySpark DataFrame? Given that the other tables (source_lrsapirefund_tmp_details and source_lrscbs_tmp_details) are in the database, is it possible to execute these queries with minimal modification?
Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Unless you are reading from a delta table, your dataframe is immutable.
